# Multiple Pages in iReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

First off, I am using a version of iReport 2.0.0.

A customer has asked for a 2 page report.  This report contains a header (which is shown on both pages with the page number and then some static information), one block of information that is queried from the Oracle server, and then about 7 static images that cover up the rest of the front page and the second.

The problem is, there is no way to create a second page in iReports.  So to work around this, I tried doubling the page size for 2 pages and inserting a page break where the first page would end.  While this looks great in iReports, when I execute it in PDF format, I get the first page with all the right information, and then 11 inches of white space, and then the page all correct, except with 11 inches of white space.

I tried shrinking the page back down to 11 inches again, however, when I do that I get a build error saying my details section is out of the margins and it just overlaps all my images and I basically just have one page again.

Does anyone have a solution for multiple pages like this?  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you using 2.0.0? That version is obsolete. They're already on 4.6.0+, and the features you want may be implemented in a later version. If you're just delivering a report, it shouldn't matter what version of iReport your using. If you have a server that needs to generate the report, then I would try to convince them to upgrade to the latest Jasper.

Comment: Well, at my company, we use a custom version of iReports that one of the previous software engineers that worked here coded, and also modified our server side jasper stuff to work with it.  In short, there is stuff that we do that iReports doesn't do itself so they added it in.  I don't know all the dirty details, I just graduated college in May and only been working here 2 months.

Comment: I know you said it should automatically extend the page, it does this usually in other reports when field information is inserted into text boxes and drawn from the server.  In this case though, I am manually placing image files in the report, uploading the images onto the server, and the report is using the images to generate the bottom 4/5 of the report.  Only the top 1/5 of the report is actually using any information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Put the page number and page header stuff in a page header band, then the database-driven data and the images in the detail band. Jasper should flow the images into the second page when it runs out of room on the first.

Comment: Thats kind of my problem though, its not.  If I have an 11 inch page and when I get to the bottom and try to insert element > image, and put it down at the bottom, it just gives me the "Element bottom reaches outside the band area" warning.

Comment: And it's in the detail band? Make sure the 'ignore pagination' report property is unchecked

Comment: It is.  Could it just be that since its on version 2.0.0 it doesn't support this feature? And should I set my page to 11 inches or 22 inches and stretch the band out?  Thanks

Comment: It's quite a possibility. A lot has changed since then. You might want to install a later version and check. You're able to install multiple versions side by side on Windows.